# Notepad++ Regex Ending With

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I want to remove all the lines until some terminating string. So something like this :

```
These
lines 
  || that can contain numbers 123 or characters like |*{
will be removed
But the following lines
will 
remain.
```

I want to obtain :

```
But the following lines
will 
remain.
```

I tried searching the regexp `/removed$/` and replacing with an empty string, but it says `0 matches`.

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Is a '.' a special character? Try excaping it with '\'

Comment: Don't mind the dot. I removed it. Sorry for that. My terminating string is actually a string with letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you check ". matches newline", and use `.*removed\.$`:

Notice that you need `.*` at the start to match everything up until the terminating string, and you have to escape the literal `.` at the end.

Also, Notepad++ doesn't want slashes around its regexes.

If you don't have the `.` at the end of your terminator, just remove the `\.` from the regex.

To remove the trailing newline as well, you could use `.*removed\r?\n?`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! So if the terminating string is "removed" without the dot, will the regex be .*removed$ ?

Comment: Thanks again! Almost perfect. One small problem though. It leaves the first line empty. So the line with "But," becomes the 2nd line, instead of the very first line. But it does not matter, so I will accept your answer (in 5 mins). If you find a solution to this problem, please post it too.